# When one thing is over, the next is just around the corner

Tags: phrase-requests, letter-writing, proverb-requests

I'm looking for an appropriate phrase to finish a semi-formal letter to a colleague.

I'm thanking him for his cooperation and looking forward to the next event we'll be preparing together. At the very end, I'd like to use some proverb (if possible) which means **"it's good that when one thing is over, the next is just around the corner"** or something like that.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: We say negative / facetious things like *Once more unto the breach!* and *Back to the grindstone!*, but I'm not sure we have any idiomatically common *positive* ways of expressing the idea *there's plenty more work to be done, and I'm really looking forward to it.* All that comes to mind for me is Boxer the hardworking, but naive and ignorant horse in George Orwell's Animal Farm: [*I will work harder*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxer_(Animal_Farm)) But he's *resigned,* rather than *enthusiastic*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the idea is thanking the colleague for fruitful cooperation. That's the point. He is not really a friend. But we've been through many things together. That's why the style of the letter should be semi-formal. Of course everyone understands that there is hard work to be done and no one is jumping for joy because of it. But again, it's simply not what the letter is about.

Comment: The standard phrasing in *business* contexts where you're thanking someone for their assistance on some earlier job is ***I look forward to working with you again** [on possible future projects].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know. But even business contexts can sometimes require something less of a cliche. Thank you anyway. I think I found what I'd been looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Done with this, and the next is in the offing"

> [in the offing](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-offing.html)
>   <sub>MEANING</sub>
>   Imminent; likely to happen soon.
>   <sub>WHAT'S THE ORIGIN OF THE PHRASE ‘IN THE OFFING’?</sub>
>
> […] 'the offing' is the part of the sea that can be seen from land, excluding those parts that are near the shore. Early texts also refer to it as 'offen' or 'offin'.
>
> Someone who was watching out for a ship to arrive would first see it approaching when it was 'in the offing' and expected to dock before the next tide. Something that is 'in the offing' isn't happening now or even in a minute or two, but will inevitably happen before long. The phrase has migrated from its naval origin into general use in the language and is now used to describe any event that is imminent.

Source: The Phrase Finder

Answer (score 3):

[When one door closes, another opens](http://quotes.yourdictionary.com/articles/who-said-when-one-door-closes-another-opens.html) is a common idiom. It seems a lot of people attribute this to Alexander Graham Bell, but I the comment on that page suggests it is older. So presumably Bell was just expanding on it.

Answer (score 0):

'**New fields / horizons beckon**' is sometimes used in this context.

I'm quite familiar with these expressions, but they don't seem to merit inclusion in dictionaries.